# Inequality for a nested family of convex sets.

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

We consider a family of bounded open convex sets in $\mathbf{R}^n$ which we'll denote $\{G_h\}_{h \in (0,1]}$. They are non-decreasing in the sense $h_1 > h_2$ implies $G_{h_1} \supseteq G_{h_2}$. Put $G:= \bigcap_{h \in (0,1]}G_h$. Let $x_0 \in G$ and $r>0$ be given. I want to prove (or alternatively find a counterexample) to the implication
$$ h_1 > h_2 \implies \frac{|G_{h_1} \cap B_r(x_0)|}{|G_{h_1}|} \leq \frac{|G_{h_2} \cap B_r(x_0)|}{|G_{h_2}|}.$$

I think the implication is true (though am not certain). The intuition being that as the sets decrease the portion contained in the ball increases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this should be a counterexample:
[image: A family of convex sets]